# Firefox not sending cookie in Ajax request (XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: firefox, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a new problem with a cross-site JavaScript request and sending cookies, but only in Firefox.

I have this code

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
               url: "https://server.com/page",
               data: $('#formdata').serialize(), 
            xhrFields: {
                  withCredentials: true
               },
              success: function(html){ 
                   alert("Thank you for your submission") 
               },
               crossDomain: true
             });
    }
```

(context: it is in an example of how CSRF attacks work)

https://server.com/page relies on a session ID cookie to be sent.  The cookie has been set, with `SameSite` set to `None` and the `Secure` flag included.  myserver.com has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to include the site making this request.  It also has

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

However, in Firefox, the session ID cookie doesn't get sent.  I am sure it used to before my most recent Firefox upgrade.  I checked in a different tab and the cookie is there, and does have the correct settings.

It works in Chrome and it works in Safari.

Does anyone know if Firefox has changed its policy recently?  Is there a setting I can configure?

My Firefox version is 104.0.2 (64 bit) and I am running on Mac (Monterey).

Answer (score 9):

Never mind, I found it.  Firefox's *Total Cookie Protection* prevents pretty much all cross-site cookie sending.  Arguably a good thing but if, like me, you do want to enable cross-site cookies, go to *Settings* in Firefox and *Privacy & Security*.  Under *Enhanced Tracking Protection*, click on *Custom* and uncheck *Cookies*.

Comment: This new feature protected me so much that it wasted hours of my life. It would be nice if they would drop a warning or any indication at all in the console about what is going on.

Comment: Also Google will start phasing out third-party cookies from Q1 2024 : https://www.techcircle.in/2023/05/19/google-will-start-phasing-out-third-party-cookies-from-q1-2024

Comment: After unchecking the *Cookies* in *Enhanced Tracking* as you suggest, setting cookie from server (express) still does **not** set cookie in firefox. So After I log in, an endpoint which sends cookie, no cookie appears in firefox so I cannot send anything back to server. So still this does not work for `Set-cookie`